# Returning best matching data objects given a boolean list

Tags: postgresql

I hope this question is appropriate for this forum.  I am setting up a PostgreSQL data base and need a few ideas on how to structure my tables so I can pull the data I need.

I know I need a table that contains information about different venues.  There will be a column for the venue name and then several columns with details about the venue each containing a boolean. So for example column 1 will have the venue name, column two will be titled food and the data cell will either be true or false.  There will be 15-20 columns.

I am going to get a list of user responses for each column (other than name) and want to return a list of venues ordered by best match.

Here is an example if I haven't been clear.
I have a table with three rows:

```
Concert Hall, Yes, Yes, Yes
Opera, Yes, No, No
First Ave, Yes, Yes, No
```

I am receiving the user input which is (No, No, No)

My  query should return: Opera, First Ave, Concert Hall.  It would be even better if I could get the % match as well (66%, 33%, 0%)

Answer (score 2):

> There will be a column for the venue name and then several columns with details about the venue each containing a boolean ... There will be 15-20 columns.

I would suggest that this is a poor design.  Those repeated, related data items held in "flag" fields in a single record sounds, to me anyway, like it can be better Normalised.

I would split out into multiple tables, something like this:

```
select * 
from venues ; 

+----+-------------------+
| id | name              | 
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Royal Albert Hall | 
|  2 | Hyde Park         |
+----+-------------------+

select * from facilities ; 

+----+----------+
| id | name     | 
+----+----------+
| 11 | Parking  | 
| 22 | Catering | 
| 33 | Seating  | 
| 44 | Indoor   | 
+----+----------+

select * 
from venue_facilities ; 

+----------+-------------+
| venue_id | facility_id | 
+----------+-------------+
|        1 |          22 | 
|        1 |          33 | 
|        1 |          44 |
|        2 |          11 |
+----------+-------------+
```

Now your searching can be done with a "group by" clause.
For example, to find "indoor" venues with "catering" ...

```
select v.name, count( vf.facility_id ) best 
from venues v 
left join venue_facility vf on v.id = vf.venue_id 
left join facilities f on vf.facility_id = f.id 
and f.name in ( 'Indoor', 'Catering' ) 
group by v.name 
-- having count( vf.facility_id ) > 0    /* Enable this line to "drop out" all the zero-rated venues */ 
order by 2 desc, 1 ; 

+-------------------+------+
| name              | best | 
+-------------------+------+
| Royal Albert Hall |    2 |
| Hyde Park         |    0 |
+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks Phill. This is the type of feedback I was hoping to get.  So if I understand correctly, you are suggesting I have one table with strict venue information (uid, venue name, address, capacity, etc.) and another table of just amenities with a uid.  Then I would use a third table to link the venue name with different amenities. I don't completely understand the query but I will play around with it and see if I can get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select *, 
       (col1 = false)::int + (col2 = false)::int + (col3 = false)::int as match
from the_table;
```